# Show new View after success login

Tags: ios, swiftui, firebase-authentication

I want to show a new view when the user is singed in successfully with firebase, but when the user is successfully logged in the app does not show the other view.

I try changing the `singedIn` variable to check if the user is singed in or not and then showing the new view but is not working

Thanks

**My code:**

```
    //
//  LoginView.swift
//  iGrow Goals
//
//  Created by George Sepetadelis on 3/8/21.
//

import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

struct LoginView: View {
    
    @State var email:String = ""
    @State var password:String = ""
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AppViewModel
    @State var singedIn = false
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Image("logo_transparent").resizable().scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .top)
                    .padding(.top, 150)
                
                Text("Sign in")
                    .font(.system(size: 45))
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                
                TextField("Email", text: $email)
                    .frame(height: 45)
                    .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
                    .padding([.horizontal], 4)
                    .cornerRadius(16)
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16).stroke(Color.gray))
                    .padding([.horizontal], 24)
                
                
                SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                    .frame(height: 45)
                    .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
                    .padding([.horizontal], 4)
                    .cornerRadius(16)
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16).stroke(Color.gray))
                    .padding([.horizontal], 24)
                    .padding(.top)
                    .padding(.bottom, 30)
                
                    
                Text("Sign in")
                    .font(.system(size: 25))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .frame(width: 220, height: 50)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(40)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        if (email == "" || password == "") {
                            print("empty input")
                        }else {
                            viewModel.signIn(email: email, password: password)
                            
                            if (Auth.auth().currentUser?.email != nil) {
                                singedIn = true
                            }else {
                                singedIn = false
                                print("not singed in")
                            }
                            
                        }
            }
            .padding(.bottom, 500)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
                
            if singedIn {
                SignUpView()
            }
            
            /*
             NavigationLink(destination: LoginView().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)) {
             Text("Go to second screen")
             }*/
        }
        .navigationTitle("")
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}

struct LoginView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LoginView()
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of SwiftUI is based on changing state variables.
onTapGesture is not the place to "return" a View. Try something like this to change the state of isSignedIn:

```
   @State var isSignedIn = false
    
    Text("Sign in")
        .font(.system(size: 25))
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .padding()
        .frame(width: 220, height: 50)
        .background(Color.blue)
        .cornerRadius(40)
        .onTapGesture {
            if (email == "" || password == "") {
                print("empty input")
            }else {
                viewModel.signIn(email: email, password: password)
                if (Auth.auth().currentUser?.email != nil) {
                    isSignedIn = true
                } else {
                    print("not singed in")
                    isSignedIn = false
                }
            }
        }
    
  //  if isSignedIn {
  //      SignUpView()
  //  }

  // EDIT
    NavigationLink("", destination: SignUpView(), isActive: $isSignedIn)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It still not working

Comment: you will have to show us more code, so we can help you track down your issues.

Comment: I see. You could do this, to go to the SignUpView: `NavigationLink("", destination: SignUpView(), isActive: $singedIn)` instead of: `if singedIn { SignUpView()  }`

Comment: Thank you very very much